# 2D коллайдеры не касаются друг друга в UNITY

Tags: unity3d

Есть 2D сцена, на сцене спрайт с Box Collider2D, выше такой же спрайт но уже с RigidBody2D.

На обеих обьектах нет никаких скриптов.
При запуске сцены спрайт расположенный  выше падает на нижнюю, но не впритык, не ложиться на него а остается зазор и ливитирует. А если потянуть в низ и отпустить амортизирут возвращается верх на длину зазора.

Ни в бокс коллайдере не в RigidBody2D ничего не менял, все по дефолту и Юнити тоже.
Менял версии от 2019Lts до 2021beta, не помогло проблема сохранилась. В 3D такой проблемы нет.
Хотел платформер сделать, все встало в самом начале. Буду благодарен за любую помошь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не показали коллайдер второго обьекта, я ни вижу зазора. Разве обьект падает по физике не верно?

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev там 2 одинаковых стандартно созданных куба, как он написал. Коллайдер второго куба так же по черному контуру.

Comment: @Andrew, глаз замылился) только увидел всю картину что это 2 черных квадрата

Answer (score 2):

В настройках физики по пути `Player Settings` -> `Physics 2D` есть поле `Default Contact Offset` стоит выбрать значение равное - **0**.

Что сделает соответственно смещение между контактами коллайдеров нулевым, оно по умолчанию имеет другое значение

[image: Default Contact Offset]